# Android application error with logcat

Tags: java, android

when I run my application on my mobile phone I get the error:

unfortunately the app gemdata has stopped when I press the togglebutton

I can't figure out what is wrong, can anyone help?

thanks to Wesley I found that the problem occurede because I had set the Onclick attribute in my xml File

My code looks like this:

```
package dk.SimonPedersen.gemdata2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public static final String GEMFFS = "dk.SimonPedersen.GEMFFS";

protected static final boolean Sex = false;

SharedPreferences ada;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
Button btnGem;
ToggleButton tbKon;
EditText etVaegt;
Double sex;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ada = getSharedPreferences(GEMFFS, 0);
    editor = ada.edit();

    btnGem = (Button) findViewById (R.id.btnGem);
    tbKon = (ToggleButton) findViewById (R.id.tbKon);
    etVaegt = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.etVaegt);

    tbKon.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                sex=0.7d;
            } else {
                sex=0.6d;
            }    
        }
    });
}   
}
```

this is the Errors I get in logcat:

```
11-13 14:59:07.635: D/AndroidRuntime(12858): Shutting down VM
11-13 14:59:07.635: W/dalvikvm(12858): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414e4700)
11-13 14:59:07.635: E/AndroidRuntime(12858): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-13 14:59:07.635: E/AndroidRuntime(12858): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not       find a method onToggleClicked(View) in the activity class dk.SimonPedersen.gemdata2.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.ToggleButton with id 'tbKon'
11-13 14:59:07.635: E/AndroidRuntime(12858):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3620)
11-13 14:59:07.635: E/AndroidRuntime(12858):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
11-13 14:59:07.635: E/AndroidRuntime(12858):    at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:100)
11-13 14:59:07.635: E/AndroidRuntime(12858):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17722)
11-13 14:59:07.635: E/AndroidRuntime(12858):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
11-13 14:59:07.635: E/AndroidRuntime(12858):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-13 14:59:07.635: E/AndroidRuntime(12858):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-13 14:59:07.635: E/AndroidRuntime(12858):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5303)
11-13 14:59:07.635: E/AndroidRuntime(12858):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-13 14:59:07.635: E/AndroidRuntime(12858):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-13 14:59:07.635: E/AndroidRuntime(12858):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
11-13 14:59:07.635: E/AndroidRuntime(12858):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
11-13 14:59:07.635: E/AndroidRuntime(12858):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-13 14:59:07.635: E/AndroidRuntime(12858): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: onToggleClicked [class android.view.View]
11-13 14:59:07.635: E/AndroidRuntime(12858):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:423)
11-13 14:59:07.635: E/AndroidRuntime(12858):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:787)
11-13 14:59:07.635: E/AndroidRuntime(12858):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3613)
11-13 14:59:07.635: E/AndroidRuntime(12858):    ... 12 more
```

Comment: post your logcat

Comment: post the logcat message, which the line number of the crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your xml file for the ToggleButton with id tbKon.

I think you have set the onClick attribute in the xml file,
which looks like onClick="onToggleClicked"